# I want to know more about the >> programming operator

Tags: syntax, operators

I game maker language or other languages what does this mean

```
c = (col >> 24) & 255
```

Comment: Search on Google.  This question is too broad for this site.

Comment: @Jamal have you ever tried searching for little code snippets on Google?  It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In Java/C/C++ it's a right shift operation.

Answer (score 0):

> > is the right shift operator, one of the many bitwise operators. It is roughly equivalent to dividing by two and rounding down, IF you're using integers.

For integers, every number is represented in binary. 24 is represented as such:

11000

Shifting right pushes all these values to the "right"; so we lose the rightmost zero!

1100 is "12" in binary.

Continuing to do so would yield us this:

110 ("6")

11 ("3")

1 ("1")

0

Answer (score 0):

In this context, it's usually extracting one of the colour components from a 32-bit ARGB value (typically the alpha component in the most significant byte)

Given four bytes in an integer ordered `ARGB`, the right shift discards the right-most 24 bits (`RGB`) leaving only `A`.

The `&` operation ensures that any bits that were originally to the left of `A` (or extended sign-bits) are ignored.